# how to select an object from a list which is an attribute of another object in a database with spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two classes where one of them contains a Map of objects of the second class, and I want to make a query to find one object by its id.
here's my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="objectx", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"objectxId"}))
public class Objectx {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private int objectxId;


@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "objectx_objecty",  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "objectxId") , 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "objectyId") )
@MapKeyColumn(name="objecty_name")
private Map<String, objecty> objectyMap;
```

in the objectyRepository, I have:

```
public interface ObjectyRepository extends CrudRepository<Objecty, Long> {   
public static final String FIND_OBJECTY_BY_OBJECTYID_OBJECTXID = 
        "SELECT y from Objecty y "
                + "JOIN y.Objectx x "
                +   "WHERE x.objectxId =:objectxId "
                +   "AND y.objectyId =:objectyId";

@Query(FIND_OBJECTY_BY_OBJECTYID_OBJECTXID)
public Objecty findObjectyByObjectyIdAndObjectxId(@Param("ObjectxId")           
          int ObjectxId, @Param("ObjectyId") String ObjectyId);
```

Can anyone tell  me how to get the needed result, please?

I'm working with eclipse Kepler and using spring and hibernate

the error I get is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Objectx of: com.domain.Objecty
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:367)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:500)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:649)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:272)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:219)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:126)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:386)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3858)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3644)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
... 80 common frames omitted
```

Here's the two classes:

```
package com.domain;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name="objecty", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"objectyId"}))
public class Objecty {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;


@Column(name="objectyId")
private String objectyId;

private String objectyName;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="objectyMap")
private Set<Objectx> objectxSet = new HashSet<Objectx>(0);

public Objecty(){

}

public String getObjectyId(){
    return objectyId;
}

public void settObjectyId(String objectyId){
    this.objectyId = objectyId;
}

public String getObjectyName(){
    return objectyName;
}

public void setObjectyName(String objectyName){
    this.objectyName = objectyName;
}

public Set<Objectx> getObjectx() {
    return objectxSet;
}

public void setObjectxSet(Set<Objectx> objectxSet) {
    this.objectxSet = objectxSet;
}
```

}

and:

```
package com.domain;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.MapKeyColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name="objectx", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"objectxId"}))
public class Objectx {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private int objectxId;
private String type;
private String model;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "objectx_objecty",  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "objectxId") , 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "objectyId") )
@MapKeyColumn(name="objectyMap")
private Map<String, Objecty> objectyMap;


public Objectx(){

    objectyMap = new HashMap<String, Objecty>();  
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getobjectxId(){
    return objectxId;
}

public void setObjectxId(int objectxId){
    this.objectxId = objectxId;
}

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type){
    this.type = type;
}

public String getModel(){
    return model; 
}

public void setModel(String model){
    this.model = model; 
}

public Map<String, Objecty> getObjectyMap(){

    if(objectyMap==null){
        this.objectyMap = new HashMap<String, Objecty>();
    }
    return objectyMap;
}

public void addOrUpdateObjectyToObjectx(Objecty objecty){

    String objectyId = objecty.getObjectyId();
    if (objectyMap.containsKey(objectyId)){
        Objecty objectyTmp = objectyMap.get(objectyId); 
        objectyTmp = objecty;
    } else{
        objectyMap.put(objectyId, objecty);
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Your param names inside the `@Param` annotations don't match the parameter names in your query: `Objectxd != objectxId`. Start by fixing that. Then tell us what the concrete problem is: your input, what you expect as output, and what you actually get (including the stack trace of the exception if any).

Comment: It was just a typing mistake, sorry. and I added the error I got.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Let's say my objectx is schoolbag and objecty is book and in my school bag I have a Map of books. but I want to get one specefic book from a classroom that contains a lot of school bags. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: The error is quite clear, isn't it? There is o property named "Objectx" in Objecty. What's the code of those entities?

Comment: JB Nizet: above the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clearly stating that that the 'Objecty' class does not have the 'Objectx' that you are trying to use on the join 'JOIN y.Objectx'.

Try to switch this JOIN syntax by the following:

JOIN y.objectxSet

Doing this your query should be able to execute.

---

However, reading your code I could see a lot of confused attribute declarations and mappings, it's even hard to understand your real problem, and/or verify if it will work properly or not.

Naming your classes by the their exact behavior is almost a MUST DO thing while coding Java, even in studies and tests.

By the way, don't get me wrong, I'm just saying what's my opinion about your code organization, and stating something you could improve. There's tons of materials about Java/Hibernate mapping that will surely help you to understand it's behavior.

---

Going back to your question, let us know if the solution stated above will help you in this error.

Comment: @NOnbot: Thanks it worked perfectly. and I totaly agree with you about the code. I'm reading "Clean Code" to improve the quality of my code.